# How the figures and vertices of simplicial complex are related to Hom([m],[n]) elements of standard n-simplex (trying to grasp Kan complex in it)?

Tags: simplicial-stuff, simplicial-complex

[Kan complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kan_fibration) has nice pictorial interpretation in the [simplicial complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_complex), from the other side there is standard [$n$-simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_set#The_standard_n-simplex_and_the_simplex_category). I am trying to understand how simplicial complex (and Kan horn in it and Kan complex in these terms) can be mapped, represented by standard $n$-simplex? How the vertices in simplicial complex be mapped to the elements of mappings $([m],[n])$ and how points/line segments/triangles can be mapped to the sets of such mappings and how the definition of horn looks into standard n-simplex?

I guess that such correspondence/mapping between simplicial complex standard $n$-simplex should exist, because many definitions (e.g., the definition of the Kan complex itself) involves standard $n$-simplices and their horns. So, standard $n$-simplices as some kind of quite universal structures.